# On a stronger property than being an Armendariz ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, terminology

A ring $R$ is said to be Armendariz if $f(x), g(x) \in R[x]$ are such that $f(x)g(x) = 0$, where $f(x) = a_nx^n + \dots a_0, g(x) = b_mx^m + \dots + b_0$, then $a_ib_j=0$ for all $i,j$.

In other words, the coefficients of a polynomial in $R[x]$ which is a zero divisor must be either 0, or a zero divisor in $R$.

If a ring has this property, this is a nice characterization of the zero divisors in the polynomial ring over a ring $R$, but I've come across a stronger property: "If $f(x) \in R[x]$ is a zero divisor, then $f(x) = \eta h(x)$ for some $h(x) \in R[x]$, and $\eta \in R$ a zero divisor."

I believe that I've been able to show this property holds for $ R = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, and I believe it also holds in rings of the form $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^n \rangle$, but I'm interested to know if this stronger property characterizing the zero divisors in $R[x]$ has been studied, and if it has a proper name as of yet.

Note that this property is in fact stronger than the usual Armendariz property, as $(1,0,0)x + (0,1,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3[x]$ is a zero divisor, but calculation shows that it cannot be written as the product of a zero divisor in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and another first order polynomial.